# angular 4 project does not reload itself when i save HTML, CSS or TS file

Tags: angular, angular-cli

### versions

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.1
Node: 8.2.1
OS: linux x64
```

### And **devDependencies** like

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "4.2.4",
}
```

`ng serve` and `ng serve --watch` not working.

Comment: Did you got any error in `console`?

Comment: are you starting the app on the default port? are you pointing to the right port in the browser? does the cli ever appear to have updated the files?

Comment: no any error in console @hrdkisback

Comment: in terminal not any changes when i save file.

Comment: Try to Run this `command` in `console`  >`sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 ` and then run  >`sudo sysctl -p --system` and check.

Comment: how long have you waited to see if the app rebuilds itself? if you have a low spec machine it will probably take longer

Comment: try command in console @hrdkisback not working

Comment: thanks @hrdkisback it's  run

Comment: Glad to hear this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should **Increase the amount of inotify watchers** by running below command in `console`

```
$ sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
$ sudo sysctl -p --system
```

You can refer this link for more https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers

See above link If you like to make your limit permanent, use:

```
$ echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
$ sudo sysctl -p --system
```

Comment: @chiragsorathiya you have run this commands every time when you are restart your system.

Comment: every time .?for why ..?

Comment: it's not a better way